# Restify exception being mysteriously thrown

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, restify

I have the following Restify route handler defined.

```
MyModule.prototype.uploadDateChecker = function (req, res, next) {
    req.locals = {};
    var handlerConfig = req._self = this;

    //Uncommenting this line does throw the exception with the message.
    //next(new Error("Test Error"));

    var continueProcessing = commonUtils.processInputs(req, res, next, handlerConfig, __function, __line);
    ...
    //If I uncomment this one instead, some other exception is thrown first somewhere resulting in: {"code":"InternalError","message":""}
    //next(new Error("Test Error: "+continueProcessing));
```

For some reason, after the commonUtils.processInputs function returns, the client receives a 500 error with a message of "".  If I add a

```
next(new Error("Test Error"));
```

right before the call to processInputs, then the 500 error has a "Test Error" in the body.  If I move it to right after the processInputs, then the 500 has no message.  Apparently another exception is being thrown from inside processInputs with any message.  However, if I go into that processInputs and right before the return I add that next(new Error("Test Error")) statement, then the client gets the Test Error.  So I don't know how/why the blank message is being thrown when the throw lines are commented out.

End of ProcessInputs:

```
...
commonUtils.processOutputs = function (req, res, next, handlerConfig, func, line) {
    var resp = commonUtils.enterExit(req, res, next, handlerConfig, func, line, "START");
    //Uncommenting this line results in: {"message":"Test Error: true"}
    //next(new Error("Test Error: "+resp));

    return resp;

}
```

HTTP Response Body without the message:

```
{"code":"InternalError","message":""}
```

HTTP Response Body with the message (inside processInputs):

```
{"message":"Test Error: true"}
```

Comment: None of this looks very restify like. Are you sure this is about restify?

Comment: @Head Coder, are all helper functions used by my Restify router handlers and I passed in req ,res, and next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that inside of commonUtils.processInputs I was calling eval, which threw an error and I immediately caught.  I then called next(err.message+"some other text") instead of next(new Error(errmessage+"some other text"));  Since "next(err)" expects err to be an Error object, a new Error due to the syntax error was thrown.